# How to route my admin sign up to go to an admin page using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I first used Devise to create authorization for Users. Then I wanted to create a separate Admin user using Devise. I followed these directions from Devise using Option 1: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role.

I created my admin model and migration, added an admin into the database `Admin.create(etc...)`

I added an admin button on the homepage: `<%= link_to "Admin", new_admin_session_path %>`

My problem is that I click the admin button, the route does takes me to: `http://localhost:3000/admins/sign_in`, which is correct, but when I sign in, it goes to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`. I do have flash messages so the flash message says the admin is signed in successfully. I think it has to do with my routes, because the Devise User and Devise Admin routes are the same. How do I configure this to go to admin views(I'm going to create an admin dashboard) and not mess up Devise Admin authorizations?

Here are my current routes:

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
        new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
            admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_password POST   /admins/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_password GET    /admins/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_password GET    /admins/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH  /admins/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /admins/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_registration GET    /admins/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
       admin_registration POST   /admins(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
   new_admin_registration GET    /admins/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
  edit_admin_registration GET    /admins/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                          PATCH  /admins(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /admins(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /admins(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
              deals_index GET    /deals/index(.:format)                     deals#index
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                  devise/sessions#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                    devise/registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                   devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                      devise/registrations#edit
                          PATCH  /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: Show the admin login view

Comment: I don't have an admin login view. For views, I only have a folder named Devise, and the views for devise in them. I know I'll probably need another set of views but I tried that. The routes stayed the same however and I already have devise_for :admins in the routes.rb file. I used `rails g devise:views admins` but that doesn't do anything for the routes.